# React native: How to move Input from center to top with animation?

Tags: javascript, react-native, flexbox

I'm trying to make an Input, that will be moved from center to top when user start typing some text. How can I change `justifyContent: 'center'` for `justifyContent: 'flex-start'` with animation? Or maybe I should do it in another way?

My code:

```
<View style={styles.container}>
  <SearchInput
    onChangeText={this.handleInputChange}
  />
</View>
```

and styles:

```
const styles = {
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    alignItems: 'stretch',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    flexDirection: 'column'
  }
};
```

Comment: Are you found any way?

Comment: Any updates guys?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65788377/react-native-animation-how-to-move-text-from-center-to-left-with-animation

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should be able to achieve that for free by using [`LayoutAnimation`](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/layoutanimation.html).

This is what you would do, obviously some things are left out:

```
handleFocus = () => {
  LayoutAnimation.easeInEaseOut();
  this.setState({
    isSearching: true,
  });
};

render() {
  const style = {
    justifyContent: this.state.isSearching
      ? 'flex-start'
      : 'center',
  };
  return (
    <TextInput onFocus={this.handleFocus} style={style} />
  );
}
```

If this doesn't work, which I doubt, you would have to use [`Animated`](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/animated.html).

Comment: This is good idea while Animated interpolate cannot transit string value. (y)