# React Native animation - How to move Text from center to left with animation?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I need to move text from the center to the left with animation, I can't do it with screenWidth/2 with marginLeft because then I need to understand the text length and other stuff to put it in the center.

Maybe there is a way to use Interpolate with  'justifyContent' or 'alignItems', any other way will be welcome.

```
   const leftInterpolate = createInterpolate(animatedValue, [0, 1], ['center','flex-start']);
    <Animated.Text style={{justifyContent: leftInterpolate}}>
        {'blabla'}
      </Animated.Text>
```

**Update:**

I got an error when I tried the first answer:

The problem is that i can't use ref with 'Animated.View'

```
 <Animated.View ref={ref} />
```

In RN 0.61.5

**Soultion for 0.61.5 and less:**

```
import React from 'react';
import { Animated, Easing, Text, View, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';

export default function App() {
  const ref = React.useRef(View.prototype);
  const animatedValue = React.useRef(new Animated.Value(0)).current;
  const [xPos, setXPos] = React.useState(-1);

  const startAnimation = () => {
    Animated.timing(animatedValue, {
      toValue: 1,
      duration: 1000,
      delay: 1000,
      easing: Easing.linear,
      useNativeDriver: true,
    }).start();
  };

  React.useEffect(() => {
    ref.current?.measure((x, y, w, h, xAbs, yAbs) => {
      setXPos(xAbs);
    });
    startAnimation();
  }, [xPos]);

  const translateX = animatedValue.interpolate({
    inputRange: [0, 1],
    outputRange: [0, -xPos],
  });

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Animated.View style={{ transform: [{ translateX }] }}>
        <Text ref={ref}>Some Text</Text>
      </Animated.View>
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can measure the absolute `X` position of your text and translate it accordingly. Try the [demo](https://snack.expo.io/_VzlWVXF7).

```
import React from 'react';
import { Animated, Easing, Text, View, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';

export default function App() {
  const ref = React.useRef(View.prototype);
  const animatedValue = React.useRef(new Animated.Value(0)).current;
  const [xPos, setXPos] = React.useState(0);

  const startAnimation = () => {
    Animated.timing(animatedValue, {
      toValue: 1,
      duration: 1000,
      delay: 1000,
      easing: Easing.linear,
      useNativeDriver: true
    }).start();
  }

  React.useEffect(() => {
    ref.current.measure((x, y, w, h, xAbs, yAbs) => setXPos(xAbs));
    startAnimation();
  }, []);

  const translateX = animatedValue.interpolate({
    inputRange: [0, 1],
    outputRange: [0, -xPos]
  })

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Animated.View ref={ref} style={{ transform: [{ translateX }] }}>
        <Text>Some Text</Text>
      </Animated.View>
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center'
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks I'm getting the error 'ref.current.measure is undefined', which RN did you use? I use RN 0.61.5

Comment: I took your code and tried to run it, I think that the ref is not the same in your RN version because I use a older one
this is the ts error that I get under 'ref={ref}'  here:
"Type '{ children: Element; ref: MutableRefObject<View>; style: { transform: { translateX: AnimatedInterpolation; }[]; }; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & AnimatedProps<ViewProps> & { children?: ReactNode; }'.
  Property 'ref' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & AnimatedProps<ViewProps> & { children?: ReactNode; }'."

Comment: @barak109 Please insert your code to find what is wrong there.

Comment: As i mention i took your code from the snack copied it to a new file and then rendering him, so the problem is in the RN version

Comment: I updated my question, thank you for the help : ) , do you have any idea how can I pass the problem that I mentioned?

Comment: Are you using class based component?

Comment: No, i use your code.. functional component

Comment: @barak109 Try to use `ref.current.getNode().measure` instead.

Comment: Again i can't use ref with <Animated.View/> in RN 0.61.5 so i found out a solution, you can see that I updated my question. Thanks!

Comment: If `getNode()` does not work then you can add an extra `View` and wrap `Animated View`. `<View ref={ref}><Animated.View><Text>...`

Comment: A better way is to give it to the <Text ref={}/> like the answer that I post : )

Comment: Sorry I didn’t notice it. Yes, it’s the solution